# QT Eclipse Integration - Adding External Libs

Tags: eclipse, qt, boost

I have set up the latest eclipse+cdt  +  mingw  +  qt  +  qt-eclipse-integration.

I have 2 Problems:

1. When i create "New -> Qt Gui Project" it doesn't add the mingw includes (when i click new c++ project it adds them)
2. I would like to use boost, too. How do I tell eclipse/qmake to add the .lib's ?

Thank you
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :)
If you want to add external include path or library to the project, then you have to modifye the xxxx.pro file-t.
Details here:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath

Good luck!
Istvan